# MysqlDataAdapter.Update not throwing exception

Tags: vb.net, server, drag

In my application I have drag and drop functionality for a TreeView and for a DataGridView.

It works great and I have no issues with the code.

I use Visual Basic - Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit. After Building Release it also works fine on Windows 10 when running release.
I then copy it to a Windows 2008 R2 Virtual server where it is run by each user through Remote Desktop.

The strange issue I have is that the TreeView drag and drop functionality works 100%, but the DataGridView seems to ignore my drop - only on the Server.

I can't find anything on the net that relate to this.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this issue?

======================================================================

After tediously adding messages between lines I came to the conclusion that it is the MySqlDataAdapter.Update() line that is not executing.
No exception, just stops at this line and throws me out of the DataGridView.DragDrop Sub.

So the new question is, how do I catch that error after compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I probably asked the question too quickly, apologies.

For anyone that does not get an exception from MySqlDataAdapter, check permission on triggers.

In this case on my development computer root user can access from %.
On the server root is configured for access from localhost only.

One of the triggers was defined "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER..." and after changing it to `root@localhost` it worked.